# Filtering of sql output

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I want to migrate the database.
When I disable the constraints before adding the data to the output file I get extra lines:

```
SQL> spool disable_constraints.sql;
SQL> select 'alter table '||table_name||' disable constraint '||constraint_name||';' 
from all_constraints where owner = 'THE_OWNER' and constraint_name not like 'BIN%';
SQL> spool off;
```

Part of disable_constraints.sql:

```
SQL> select 'alter table '||table_name||' disable constraint '||constraint_name||';' from all_constraints where owner = 'THE_OWNER' and constraint_name not like 'BIN%';

    'ALTERTABLE'||TABLE_NAME||'DISABLECONSTRAINT'||CONSTRAINT_NAME||';'              
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    alter table DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK disable constraint SYS_C0012929;               
    alter table DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK disable constraint SYS_C0012930;               
    alter table DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK disable constraint PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK;   
    alter table DATABASECHANGELOG disable constraint SYS_C0012932;                   
    alter table DATABASECHANGELOG disable constraint SYS_C0012933;                   
    alter table DATABASECHANGELOG disable constraint SYS_C0012934;                   
    alter table DATABASECHANGELOG disable constraint SYS_C0012935;                   
    alter table DATABASECHANGELOG disable constraint SYS_C0012936;                   
    alter table DATABASECHANGELOG disable constraint SYS_C0012937;                   
    alter table ARCH_TA1_TOTAL_ENTECONOMICS disable constraint SYS_C0012938;       
    alter table ARCH_TA1_TOTAL_ENTECONOMICS disable constraint SYS_C0012939;       

    'ALTERTABLE'||TABLE_NAME||'DISABLECONSTRAINT'||CONSTRAINT_NAME||';'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    alter table ARCH_TA1_TOTAL_ENTECONOMICS disable constraint SYS_C0012940;
    alter table ARCH_TA1_TOTAL_ENTECONOMICS disable constraint SYS_C0012941;
    ....
```

For example, an extra line in the file:

```
'ALTERTABLE'||TABLE_NAME||'DISABLECONSTRAINT'||CONSTRAINT_NAME||';'              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to filter out the extra lines?
I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you should configure SQL*Plus output. Documentation what can be done and how to do that is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm).

In your case it is:

```
SET HEADING OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Mindaugas Riauba wrote, I think you just want to SET PAGESIZE 0; which should do [what you want](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2389479).